# Hook up propane fire pit to house hook up

Tags: propane

I have a valve on the supply line from a 250 gallon propane tank. I bought a propane fire pit/heater and I’m not sure how to connect the two. The fire pit is set up to screw on a portable propane tank and I am not sure how to connect my fire pit/heater to the supply line valve.

I have enclosed pictures of both the hook up, and the hose coming from the heater.

Can someone advise me on what adapter i need and how to make the connection.

[image]

Comment: The photo of the fire pit/heater hose end seems to be missing.

Comment: Oh my gosh I also could not get a second picture to upload. It is like any regular screw on you would get from a propane grill. Thank you so incredibly much for even looking at my post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see there is a male "flare" fitting, so you'll need a female flare to mate with  it.

It sounds like at the fire pit you'll need a male tank adapter.

I'm not sure you'll find that as an assembly, so you'll want to look into how to make and test gas line connections. You need either gas-tolerant PTFE thread tape or thread compound paste.

Comment: I have an adapter similar to what you are describing I got online from Mr heater there were different connections available kind of spendy but I was able to setup larger tank and run my big crab cooker outside (small tanks freeze up with that). You may need to remove the regulator if you already reduce the pressure from your tank.